# Probability density function of two uniformly distributed stochastic variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

I'm currently stuck on an exercise involving two independent stochastic variables X and Y.

Both X and Y ~ U(0,1) (uniform distribution)

The goal of the exercise is to calculate the probability density function of 
$$
Z =\ln{ \bigg(\cfrac{\max(X,Y)}{\min(X,Y)}}\bigg)
$$
I got stuck and looked at the solutions manual, and don't seem to understand how 
 $$ 
P \bigg(\ln{ \bigg(\cfrac{\max(X,Y)}{\min(X,Y)}}\bigg) \leq z \bigg)
$$

can be rewritten as

$$
P({Y \leq e^z \cdot X} \cap { X \leq Y}) + P({X \leq e^z \cdot Y} \cap { Y\leq X})
$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I imagine the ln to exponential part is no problem. The solution breaks up the problem into two **cases**, (i) $X\le Y$ and (ii) $Y\le X$. In Case (i) the max is $Y$, the min is $X$, so we want $\Pr\left(\frac{Y}{X} \le e^z\right)$, that is, $\Pr(Y\le e^z X)$. The second case is similar.

Comment: Yeah, the problem was how to handle the max and min function but now it is very obvious, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get
$$
  \log\frac{X\vee Y}{X\wedge Y} \leq z \iff X\vee Y \leq \mathrm e^z(X\wedge Y) 
$$
$$
  \iff X\leq\mathrm e^z Y,Y\leq X \text{ or }Y\leq\mathrm e^z X,Y\geq X
$$
where $\wedge$ if for $\min$, $\vee$ is for $\max$, and the latter two events have intersection of zero probability.